# Highmaps custom class to path points

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, highmaps

I am building a map with multiple point selection behaviour.
Currently I manage to work with single country selection
this is the point click event:

Here is the point click event:

```
point: {
            events:{
                click: function(e){
                    //Reset dropdowns
                    $('.popup select').prop('selectedIndex',0);

                    //Reset popup info
                    $('.popup .text').html('');

                    //store path access string
                    var thisPath = 'svg path.highcharts-key-'+e.currentTarget.code.toLowerCase();

                    //Change color of selected path
                    $(thisPath).css({fill:'rgb(20,200,0)'});

                    //Add a data attr to popup div
                    $('.popup').attr('data-country-class', 'highcharts-key-'+e.currentTarget.code.toLowerCase());

                    //Update popup INFO
                    $('.popup .market .text')   .html(e.currentTarget.name);
                    $('.popup .region .text')   .html(e.currentTarget.region);
                    $('.popup .sz .text')       .html(e.currentTarget.stabZone);

                    //Listen to market dropdown change
                    $('.popup .market select').change(function  (e) {

                        //Currently selected country class
                        var countryClass = $(this).parents('.popup').attr('data-country-class');

                        if(this.value === 'exclude'){
                            $('svg path.'+countryClass).css({fill: 'rgb(200,20,0)'});
                        }
                        if(this.value === 'include'){
                            $('svg path.'+countryClass).css({fill: 'rgb(20,200,0)'});
                        }
                        if(this.value === 'remove'){
                            $('svg path.'+countryClass).css({fill: 'rgb(208, 220, 230)'});
                        }
                    });


                    $('.popup').hide().fadeIn(500).css({left:e.pageX+30, top: e.pageY-90});
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the popup markup

```
<div class="popup">
    <p class="market">
        <span><strong class="text"></strong></span>
         <select name="market-include" id="market-include">
            <option value="include">Include</option>
            <option value="exclude">Exclude</option>
             <option value="remove">Remove</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p class="region">
        <span><strong class="text"></strong></span>
        <select name="region-include" id="region-include">
            <option value="include">Include</option>
            <option value="exclude">Exclude</option>
            <option value="remove">Remove</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p class="sz">
        <span>Stability Zone <strong class="text"></strong></span>
        <select name="sz-include" id="sz-include">
            <option value="include">Include</option>
            <option value="exclude">Exclude</option>
            <option value="remove">Remove</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to select multiple countries at once when the region  gets the value include.

This is an example of a country json definition

```
{  
  "code":"US",
  "value":34,
  "name":"United States",
  "region": "AMER",
  "stabZone": "1a"
}
```

I was looking for a way to add a region class to each path but I can't find a way to do it.

Currently each path has a class. E.g. US path has the following class=" highcharts-name-united-states of america highcharts-key-us"

I'd like to find a way to add a region class as well e.g. highcharts-region-AMER

Can anybody help me on doing this?.

I really appreciate it!

Comment: But in general, what is your goal, what should happen, could you descirbe step by step?

Comment: Hello Sebastian, you can check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/Fr56A/5/ what I am trying to accomplish is that once the second dropdown from the popup gets the value include the whole region should be selected.

Comment: E.g. If you select U.S.A. and then in the popup youll get 3 dropdowns. The first is for the country, and the second is for the region, when the region dropdown gets included several countries should be selected

Comment: I found a way to do that with the country since every path has a class that is automatically applied. E.g. Us path has this class: highcharts-key-us, I wanted to find a way to apply a region class to each path to be able to $('.highcharts-region-AMER').css({fill:someCOlor});

Comment: It is still unclear, because ok, I click on the USA (see tooltip, all of parameters are on "include" option, then select a Russia, also all parameters are "included" and what next?